# html select droplist not working inside div

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a webpage but due to some problems I don't know why my drop list is not working. However when placed outside the div it does work. I would be grateful if someone can help me please. The html and the css files are attached below.

below is the html codes:

```css
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */
 body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-image: url("background.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 canvas {
   border: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);
 }
 .outer {
   display: table;
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .middle {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #div_canvas {
   float: left;
   width: 900px;
   height: 600px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   margin-left: 50px;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #div_menu {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   float: right;
   width: 300px;
   height: 600px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   margin-right: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Menu-->
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">

      <div id="div_menu">

        <br/>
        <center>
          <select id="action">
            <option value="1">Line</option>
            <option value="2">Freehand</option>
          </select>
        </center>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <!--Canvas-->
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">

      <center>
        <div id="div_canvas">
          <canvas id="canvas" width="899" height="599"></canvas>
        </div>
      </center>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used in HTML5

Comment: Basically though, you have absolutely positioned the two `.outer` divs on top of each other. Not sure what the intent is here but that's the issue.

Comment: '<center>' still rocks your world '</center>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `.outer` Is in front of your selectbox.
Give the first `.outer` a `z-index: 1;`

Answer (score 0):

They are overlapping, don't open new divs for the canvas like this:

```css
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */
 body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-image: url("background.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 canvas {
   border: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);
 }
 .outer {
   display: table;
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .middle {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #div_canvas {
   float: left;
   width: 900px;
   height: 600px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   margin-left: 50px;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #div_menu {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   float: right;
   width: 300px;
   height: 600px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   margin-right: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Menu-->
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">

      <div id="div_menu">

        <br/>
        <center>
          <select id="action">
            <option value="1">Line</option>
            <option value="2">Freehand</option>
          </select>
        </center>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <!--Canvas-->
  

      <center>
        <div id="div_canvas">
          <canvas id="canvas" width="899" height="599"></canvas>
        </div>
      </center>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```